# Does javascript or jQuery have any technique to create a holding object that end user can shrink or expand on the fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

see this gwt Panel

http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwSplitLayoutPanel

The user can shrink or expand to make the space holding the text smaller or bigger depending on their need.

My question is:

**Does javascript or jQuery have any technique to create a holding object that end user can shrink or expand like that?**

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy native method to do this in javascript or jQuery, but jQuery UI has a re-sizable component.

https://jqueryui.com/resizable/

This does't replicate the behaviour of the google web toolkit example. This is quite complicated behavior. If you open the DOM inspector in chrome, you can see each section has an inline style with the width height and position. These are then recalculated and updated when you drag the bars.

Comment: I don't know, it works fine for me. Google 'jQuery UI resizable'